# Make a skype call from commandline

Tags: command-line, skype

I am using skypeforlinux (version 8.17.0.2), I want to call a number using commandline, I've tried `skypeforlinux --callto: +91XXXXXXXXXX`, but it is not working (It just opens skype).

Comment: I'm not familiar with `skypeforlinux`, but the normal syntax for long options is `--option=value` or `--option value` so try `--callto=+91XXXXXXXXXX` or `--callto +91XXXXXXXXXX`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from [this article on safaribooksonline.com](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/skype-hacks/0596101899/ch04s05.html) and a bunch of other third-party sources I couldn't find any description of command-line options for `skypeforlinux`.
I tried every combination with `--callto` I could think of and couldn't get it to work either. As not even the fairly common `--version` flag is recognized by the program I'm afraid the current Skype for Linux doesn't have any command-line options at all any more – I guess they were removed when [the transition from Skype (for Linux) 4.3 to Skype for Linux 8](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_installms/end-of-life-of-skype-for-linux-43/70fe7036-ddf3-4fa3-9c06-1bca3ec0226c) was made.

Comment: I know it is possible, but i can't remember where did i find the solution last time. I tried to find it again but i can't. I remember it was working simply adding a underscore to the command line. I did on the past, but i don't preserve anything from past stuff. I'll be back posting when i can find it again.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried skypeforlinux --callto: +91XXXXXXXXXX, but it is not working (It just opens skype).

From https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/skype-hacks/0596101899/ch04s05.html it looks like there should be no space after `--callto:`.

```
Skype /callto:+442075551212 will place a call to a regular telephone number
```